# Need some python help on indentationerror

Tags: python, encryption

Update sorry hereby full error message:
File "C:\XXX\crypto.py", line 26
  elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:

IndentationError: expected an intended block

This was the complete error message.

My script raises an `IndentationError`, can you help me to fix it?

```
import os, random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

def encrypt(key, filename):
        chunksize = 64*1024
        outputFile = "(encrypted)"+filename
        filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
        IV = ''

        for i in range(16):
                IV += chr(random.randint(0, 0xFF))

        encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

        with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
                with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(filesize)
                        outfile.write(IV)

                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                                if len(chunk) == 0:

                                elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
                                        chunk += ' ' *  (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                                outfile.write(encryptor.ecrypt(chunk))

def decrypt(key. filename):
        chunksize = 64*1024
        outputFile = filename[11:]

        with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
                filesize = long(infile.read(16))
                IV = infile.read(16)

                decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

                with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
                        while True:
                                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                                if len(chunk) == 0:
                                        break
                                outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
                        outfile.truncate(filesize)

def getKey(password)
        hasher = SHA256.new(password)
        return hasher.digest()

def Main():
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to (E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt?: ")

        if choice == 'E':
                filename = raw_input("File to encrypt: ")
                password = raw_input("Password: ")
                encrypt(getKey(password), filename)
                print "Done."
        elif choice == 'D':
                filename = raw_input("File to decrypt")
                password = raw_input("Password: ")
                decrypt(geetkey(password), filename)
                print "Done."
        else: 
                print "No option selected, closing..."

if _name_ == '_name_':
        Main()
```

Comment: When you seek error hunting help, please always include the full error message. It includes information on why and *where* the error occurs.

Comment: Since i'm new i have no idea what an empty block is. Do you know how to solve it? The error says BTW it in line 26. This one: elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:. What do i need to change? thanks!

Comment: See my posted answer, it addresses this.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a colon after:

```
def getKey(password)
```

You also have nothing after:

```
if len(chunk) == 0:
```

If you don't want anything there, you can add a `pass` statement as a placeholder.  Python will give an error if there's nothing there.  The following will work:

```
if len(chunk) == 0:
    pass
```

Also, on the following line:

```
def decrypt(key. filename):
```

The period needs to be a comma.

Comment: Damn, did you notice these by eyes or did you lint it? Good eye if it's the former.

Comment: @Eddo I just did a quick visual scan.

Comment: Thanks did as you told. Now I have a new error: File "C:\crypto.py", line 31 def decrypt(key. filename): SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Yes, change the period to a comma.  I also updated my answer to include this correction (refresh and look at the bottom of my answer).

Comment: On youtube was this code running flawlessly but here another error:File "C:/coding/crypto.py", line 50
    def getKey(password)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, any idea, thanks again!

Comment: I already addressed that.  It's the first thing in my post.  There's a missing colon at the end of the line.  Just add it.